# Says left hand side must be resolved to variable?

Tags: java, eclipse, breakout

I am trying to clean up code for class and when creating collision method, Eclipse keeps giving me errors that "the left hand side of an assignment must be resolved to a variable. This error is occurring at all my if statements. I know this problem is probably very simple but very similar code is working for my peers and i can't seem to resolve why mine would be different. Thanks!

```
private GObject getCollidingObject (double x, double y) {
        AudioClip bounceClip = MediaTools.loadAudioClip("bounce.au");
        if (getElementAt(x, y) =! null) {
            return (getElementAt(x, y));
            bounceClip.play();
        }
        else if (getElementAt(x + 2 * BALL_RADIUS, y) =! null) {
            return(getElementAt(x + 2 * BALL_RADIUS, y);
            bounceClip.play();
        }
        else if (getElementAt(x + 2 * BALL_RADIUS, y + 2 * BALL_RADIUS) =! null) {
            return(getElementAt(x + 2 * BALL_RADIUS, y + 2 * BALL_RADIUS));
            bounceClip.play();
        }
        else if (getElementAt(x, y + 2 * BALL_RADIUS) =! null) {
            return(getElementAt(x, y + 2 * BALL_RADIUS));
            bounceClip.play();
        } else {
            return null; 
        }
```

Comment: Did you mean `!=` instead of `=!`?

Comment: As a side note, `bounceClip.play()` will never be executed because you `return` right before calling it.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `!=` and not `=!`

Your `condition` should be:

```
 if (getElementAt(x, y) != null) {...}
```

`else if (getElementAt(x + 2 * BALL_RADIUS, y) != null) {...}`

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

`=!` isn't the "is not" comparison (`!=`). `=!` is actually the two operators `=` and `!`. Or in other words: your code trys to invert `null` and assign the inverse to a method-call.

If you want to check for "is not", use `!=`.

Answer (score 0):

`=!` is interpreted like this

```
<something> = !(boolean)
//var here = negation(boolean)
```

And you have this code:

```
getElementAt(x, y) =! null
```

Thus the compiler error.

Fix it by using different than `!=` operator.

After that, other problem is here:

```
return (getElementAt(x, y));
bounceClip.play();
```

This will raise another compiler error since cannot be more code to execute after `return`. Not sure how to fix it because I don't know your real intention here.